# Is it possible to embed a SwiftUI Table (iOS 16) into a horizontal scrollview?

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I've tried embedding a SwiftUI Table on iPadOS 16 into a horizontal scrollview, but when I do that, nothing is actually presented.

The main problem is that I have a table which has a lot of columns and I want to be able to display them all and have the user be able to scroll through them.

If not, is there an alternative, or maybe I just need to make my own sort of table?

Answer (score 0):

yes, but need to set up the frame width of table. Otherwise, it might not "showing"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation it provides horizontal scrolls automatically but only on macOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table
[image]

It seems now that table in swiftui don't get along with scrollview. So it's better decision to put table outside scroll view, or set frame. But it doesn't look like good decision [image]

With frame on table you have to calculate by yourself desired width and height of your table. And after that it will be visible inside scrollview